# flatten/dissolve/merge entire shapefile

Tags: gis, geojson, shapefile, gdal, ogr2ogr

I've been using `ogr2ogr` to do most of what I need with shapefiles (including dissolving them). However, I find that for big ones, it takes a REALLY long time.

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

`ogr2ogr new.shp old.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Union(geometry) FROM old"`

In certain instances, one might want to dissolve common neighboring shapes (which is what I think is going on here in the above command). **However, in my case I simply want to flatten the entire file and every shape in it regardless of the values (I've already isolated the shapes I need).**

- Is there a faster way to do this when you don't need to care about the values and just want a shape that outlines the array of shapes in the file?

Answer (score 3):

If you have isolated the shapes, and they don't have any shared boundaries, they can be easily collected into a single MULTIPOLYGON using ST_Collect. This should be really fast and simple to do:

```
ogr2ogr gcol.shp old.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Collect(geometry) FROM old"
```

---

If the geometries overlap and the boundaries need to be "dissolved", then ST_Union must be used. Faster spatial unions are done  with a cascaded union technique, [described here for PostGIS](https://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2009/01/must-faster-unions-in-postgis-14.html). It is supported by OGR, but it doesn't seem to be done elegantly.

Here is a two step SQL query. First make a MULTIPOLYGON of everything with ST_Collect (this is fast), then do a self-union which should trigger a [UnionCascaded()](https://web.archive.org/web/20180723234109/http://www.gdal.org:80/classOGRGeometry.html#a2ba2d777083c60fe707a40d2adc36f20) call.

```
ogr2ogr new.shp old.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Union(gcol, gcol) FROM (SELECT ST_Collect(geometry) AS gcol FROM old) AS f"
```

Or to better view the actual SQL statement:

```
SELECT ST_Union(gcol, gcol)
FROM (
  SELECT ST_Collect(geometry) AS gcol
  FROM old
) AS f
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike. This is a nice lead but seems to still take forever. Perhaps I'll look at PostGIS. Will leave this open a little longer and then accept. Could be at a dead end.

Comment: @stewart715 does ST_Collect (only) take forever, or the combined query? PostGIS is more mature than SpatiaLite, where your initial query (using just ST_Union) should work.

Answer (score -1):

I've had better success (i.e. faster) by converting it to raster then back to vector. For example:

```
# convert the vector file old.shp to a raster file new.tif using a pixel size of XRES/YRES
gdal_rasterize -tr XRES YRES -burn 255 -ot Byte -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE old.shp new.tif

# convert the raster file new.tif to a vector file new.shp, using the same raster as a -mask speeds up the processing
gdal_polygonize.py -f 'ESRI Shapefile' -mask new.tif new.tif new.shp

# removes the DN attribute created by gdal_polygonize.py
ogrinfo new.shp -sql "ALTER TABLE new DROP COLUMN DN"
```

Comment: what's a suggested XRES and YRES?